# Errors were encounted while processing : systemd

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, systemd

```
root@suraj-Inspiron-7570:/home/suraj# sudo apt-get upgrade -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,909 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Above error is found while i tried to install or upgrade my system. Please look into this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you do what the system recommended and reinstall the package? `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd`